# Delete every entry in Channel - Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine, channel

I want to delete all data in one channel. And I found that, the best way to delete all entry in channel is delete this channel and re-create it follow this article:
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-every-entry-in-a-channel

and I tried to delete channel follow this article:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_structure.html

I know that the site_id is 1 and the channel_id of channel I need to delete is 1.
But when I tried these code:

```
ee()->load->library('api'); ee()->api->instantiate('channel_structure');
$channel_id = 1;$site_id = 1;
ee()->api_channel_structure->delete_channel((int) $channel_id, [(int) $site_id]);
```

I got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/vhosts/au/admin/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code on line 7

I tried with:

```
ee()->api_channel_structure->delete_channel((int) 1, [(int) 1]);
ee()->api_channel_structure->delete_channel(1, 1);
```

But got same issue.

Does somebody know how to solve this issue. Thank so much!

Comment: If you are not getting the response you are hoping for here I'd suggest you post on the dedicated EE site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the EE documentation `(int)` is an indication that the expected value is an integer. Also, the documentation convention is that square brackets indicate optional values.

Neither is meant to be part of the code if I am reading it correctly.  I think this is what you want:

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_structure');
$channel_id = 1;
$site_id = 1;
ee()->api_channel_structure->delete_channel($channel_id, $site_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding &perpage=1000 to the end of the query string on the Edit Channel Entries screen...

E.g.
`/admin.php?S=de47727e64b2e445cfee64c85a219977c9b62474&D=cp&C=content_edit&perpage=1000`

If you run out of memory use a lower number.